# Flutter Login and Sign up Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I'm new to flutter and i need to authenticate the login and sign up pages. I have the UI ready but i don't know how to authenticate the pages. I have a database ready in my phpAdmin

Comment: There's no question here at all, but I think basically it's covered by this: [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836/5947043). Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Terminology note: PhpMyAdmin is not a database. It's just a web based administration tool for managing MySQL databases. (It is one of many such administration clients). Your PHP code would connect directly to the MySQL database server and doesn't have anything to do with PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean your form is not working? Please check the code which works for me with Firebase.
Maybe it would be helpful

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController clientEmail = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController clientPassword = TextEditingController();

  bool _obscureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('LoginView'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    elevation: 3,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          labelText: 'E-Mail',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          clientEmail = value as TextEditingController;
                        },
                        controller: clientEmail,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        validator: ((value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                            return 'Please enter E-Mail Address ';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 8),
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    elevation: 3,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(_obscureText
                                ? Icons.visibility
                                : Icons.visibility_off),
                          ),
                          labelText: 'Password',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          clientPassword = value as TextEditingController;
                        },
                        obscureText: _obscureText,
                        controller: clientPassword,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        validator: ((value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                            return 'Please enter your Password, min 7 digits';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        // here would be your function which saves the data to yout database
                        //for example
                        // addUser();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Login')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to use Firebase but there's a web app version already which is connected to a mysql database and I'm required to use the same database. Creating an API to interface with the Flutter project is not the issue. Its about getting the app to interact with the app. Example is, I want to add username, email and password to the database. I already have a PHP code that inserts data to the database but how to get the data from the flutter app into the database is the problem. I thought using a TextController would solve the problem but it didn't.

Comment: i have changed my reply and insert a Form that works from me.